# How to get process metrics for a spring boot app in solarwinds

Tags: solarwinds-orion

I am trying to get process metrics - cpu and memory usage from solarwinds(SAM) for a spring boot application running in a linux environment.

Can anyone help... I am new to solarwinds.

Comment: Please share with us your approach and show where you have a particular issue

Comment: What I have done is, I have added a linux node in solarwinds. I have tried both snmp poller and agent based poller, then I am adding a application template (java application server) but while testing I am not able to get any data.
My node is added successfully but not able to add java template to monitor application process metrics.